# Translate command CURL to PHP CURL? Cloudflare API

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

I am trying to use the CloudFlare API via PHP CURL however the doc examples show as command line curl.

```
$ curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/9a7806061c88ada191ed06f989cc3dac/dns_records/9a7806061c88ada191ed06f989cc3dac" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"id":"9a7806061c88ada191ed06f989cc3dac","type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"1.2.3.4","proxiable":true,"proxied":false,"ttl":120,"locked":false,"zone_id":"9a7806061c88ada191ed06f989cc3dac","zone_name":"example.com","created_on":"2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z","modified_on":"2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z","data":{}}'
```

Is the PUT request the same as POST? And the array at the bottom is confusing me. No idea how that translates to PHP CURL.

Comment: A cute way is to put the command, without the $, into `shell_exec()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a post but also send a custom request. Curl will then do a post style put

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

Then add the headers if needed

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [array of your headers]);
```

Change the array to be a key value array where the key is the header name and value is the header value

Comment: so the $data is the array from --data?

Comment: and the array of headers is the -H flagged strings in the request above?

Comment: Yeah if its easier you can post the string version too ? But obviously its harder to edit than an array

Comment: Yeah each -H line can be replaced with a key and value in the array